# Is it possible to add filter get parameters into google ads final url?

Tags: google-ads-api

I have catalog page with all brads included. I want users after clicking on my add to open filtered catalog page with specific brand by adding GET-parameters into url. For example:
**site.com/catalog?good=notebooks&brand=acer**

And I want to add UTM-parameters. Is it possible to make final url like:
**site.com/catalog?good=notebooks&brand=acer?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=acer_notebook&utm_content=ad1&utm_term=acer**

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused here. What's the problem with using the url: site.com/catalog?good=notebooks&brand=acer?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=acer_notebook&utm_content=ad1&utm_term=acer

This is fine in Google Ads if you're not using auto tagging. If you are using auto tagging (you should be) then you only need to use the first URL.